# How do I sort rows with price * currency rate?

Tags: mysql, join, yii

I have a table **properties** in MySQL with price and currency_id columns, and the second table is **currencies** with id and rate.

I need to calculate *price* multiplied by *currency.rate* and then sort in Yii CDbCriteria.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT data_you_want, properties.price*currency.rate AS "updated_price" FROM properties, currency WHERE properties.currency_id = currency.id ORDER BY updated_price
```